# How can I remove template parse warning - "The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead"

Tags: ng-lightning

I am getting this error at the console - 
Template parse warnings:
The  element is deprecated. Use  instead ("s-breadcrumb slds-list--horizontal">[WARNING ->]
 "): ng:///NglBreadcrumbsModule/NglBreadcrumbs.html@1:174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the new release v2.0.1 which supports Angular 4. Enjoy :)

Comment: I think the package does not exist in yarn yet. This is the package that was installed for me when i used yarn - "ng-lightning": "^1.3.0"
When I tried to edit the package.json to the version above it could not find it.

Comment: I am the author of this library and I know I have released it :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lightning

Comment: Yes it works now. Possibly yarn could not get it from npm server that first day you released it. I have installed the new version and now the error is gone. Thanks